# SQL - Combining two queries

Tags: sql, oracle

In SQL I have wrote these two queries:

Query 1:

```
SELECT HotelID, HotelName, Email FROM Hotel
WHERE HotelID IN (SELECT Branch.HotelID FROM Branch
WHERE BranchAddress LIKE '%London%');
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT Branch.HotelID, COUNT(*)
FROM Branch
GROUP BY HotelID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5;
```

I would ideally like to combine these two queries together, so that the results generated are based on either of these two.

How would i go about doing this? I thought union could be used but not sure if that is the right method to use.

Comment: `select h.HotelID,h.HotelName,h.Email,count(*) from Hotel h join Branch b on h.HotelID=b.BranchID where b.BranchAddress like %LONDON% group by h.HotelID,h.HotelName,h.Email having count(*)>5` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.hotelid, 
       a.hotelname, 
       a.email, 
       Count(*) 
FROM   hotel a 
       JOIN branch b 
         ON a.hotelid = b.hotelid 
WHERE  b.branchaddress LIKE '%London%' 
GROUP  BY a.hotelid, 
          a.hotelname, 
          a.email 
HAVING Count(*) > 5
```